# Segue to a viewcontroller in another storyboard without a navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I want to move to another viewcontroller in another storyboard and the view controller im in is not embedded in a navigationctroller.
Normally i would just instantiate the viewcontroller and push it to the navigationcontroller stack but since this is not possible i dont know what to do, and I cant seem to find any help on this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve in the app, but a few options are: present it as a modal controller, create your own custom type of segue, replace the root controller in the app's window....

Comment: its cause my login screen doesnt have a navigationcontroller. If a user login as a specific type they are lead to another part of the app which is in another storyboard

Comment: Then there's a fourth option: use a navigation controller as your root and show your login modal.  When login is finished, dismiss it and go back to the navigation controller.  Lots of possibilities.  :)

Comment: solved it with replacing root controller in the app window. Thank you for the fast response